# Getting runtime load of address error while writing code for merging two sorted linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Using a dummy node to add the lesser node of list l1 and list l2. At the end returning the location pointing next to the dummy node to get the actual merged sorted list but getting a runtime load of address with insufficient space for an object of type struct ListNode at return dummyNode->next.

```
struct ListNode* mergeTwoLists(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2) {
        if (l1 == NULL && l2 != NULL) {
                return l2;
        }
        if (l1 != NULL && l2 == NULL) {
                return l1;
        }
        struct ListNode *dummyNode = NULL;
        struct ListNode *head = NULL;

        dummyNode = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode *));
        head = dummyNode;

        while (l1 != NULL && l2 != NULL) {
                if (l1->val <= l2->val) {
                        head->next = l1;
                        l1 = l1->next;
                        head = head->next;
                }
                else {
                        head->next = l2;
                        l2 = l2->next;
                        head = head->next;
                }
        }
        if (l1 != NULL) {
                head->next = l1;
        }
        if (l2 != NULL) {
                head->next = l2;
        }    
        return dummyNode->next;
}
```

Comment: I think the malloc has wrong parameter - it should be `sizeof(struct ListNode)` instead of `sizeof(struct ListNode *)`

Comment: Please read this: [ask] and then [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] as well as minimum input that triggers the problem.

Comment: Complement to 1st comment: instead of `dummyNode = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));` write `dummyNode = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(*dummyNode));` which is less error prone. You even can drop the cast : `dummyNode = malloc(sizeof(*dummyNode));`

Answer (score 2):

Insufficient space is allocated because of passing to malloc sizeof pointer to structure `sizeof(struct ListNode *)`.
It should be changed to allocating space for whole structure -

```
dummyNode = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
```